# Get MouseListener results from one class to another Java

Tags: java, class, transfer

I have a class with panelC which contains a table populated with customer info, some textfields and buttons. Then I also have another class panelP which contains almost the same as panelC but with product info. Then in my main class I create a window with a tabbedPane and I add the above panels as tabs. My problem is that whenever I select a row in panelC table the values are transferred in a textfield, but I can't get those values in panelP class.

Any ideas on how to deal with this? :(

Comment: Store the instance of panelC in panelP so its members are accessible there.

Comment: listeners, also known as the observer design pattern would work well here.

Comment: Create Setters and Getters?

Comment: Can you post some code???